# setState inside useEffect or useCallback, dependency issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect, setstate

I'm trying to remove console warnings from my code, but I'm confused about how to solve this dependency issue.
I have a useEffect hook, that calls a method, *removeMessage*, which is defined inside my component. I get a warning that this should be in the useEffect dependency array, but if I do that, I create an infinite loop, since the function reference is re-created when the component rerenders.

```
const Component = () => {
    const [list, setList] = useState();

    const removeMessage = (message: string) => {
        const list = list.filter(x => x.message !== message);
        setList(list);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        ...
        removeMessage("test");
    });
```

So I read that I'm supposed to use the useCallback hook, to ensure the reference is not changed:

```
const removeMessage = useCallback((message: string) => {
    const list = list.filter(x => x.message !== message);
    setList(list);
}, [list]);
```

But, unless I provide my *list* as a dependency for that hook, I will get a similar warning. But if I do, I create yet another infinite loop.

This code, and usage of useEffect, is propably bad practice, but I don't know how to work around it, since my method *removeMessage* is dependent on the state to do its filtering.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the `useEffect` in the first place? Your code is synchronous and not dependent on the rendering? Or is this the part you have omitted?

Comment: @mmomtchev yes, sorry, I omitted that part. There is some logic which may result in a call to the removeMessage function.

Comment: Ok, because if you are always calling `removeMessage` this is an infinite loop.

Comment: I'm not always calling it. But the infinite loop is happening inside my useCallback, since I need to filter my state, which is dependent on the current state.

Comment: Is this condition dependent on the state? Can you move the condition outside of `useEffect()` - so that `useEffect()` is called only when it needs to call `removeMessage()`?

Comment: yes I'm afraid it is. It is an if-else statement that either updates my list directly, or calls the removeMessage method to filter a specific element. I'm using the removeMessage method several places, so this seemed like a good idea, but I guess a solution could be to move the body of the method inside my useEffect instead. The only problem then would be a bit of duplicate code.

Comment: move the function definition inside the `useEffect()` then

Comment: Then I wouldn't be able to use the function elsewhere, right?

Comment: No. The problem is that what you are doing cannot be expressed using the dependencies mechanism - because the `useEffect()` is sometimes dependent, sometimes not. Maybe you can try to completely refactor this - eventually producing two functions - or you can simply disable the warning.

Comment: Yeah, I think my "solution" will be to just move/copy the function content into my useEffect. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @mmomtchev This actually only moves my problem. Because if I move the contents, or the definition, of `removeMessage` in to my `useEffect`, then this will throw the same warning, that I have a dependency on list. Which I can't put as a dependency without creating an infinite-loop again. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work (using the setState function variant). That way you do not have a dependency on list (and it is also more correct in edge cases)

```js
const Component = () => {
  const [list, setList] = useState<Array<{ message: string }>>([]);

  const removeMessage = useCallback((message: string) => {
    setList(prev => prev.filter(x => x.message !== message));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    removeMessage('test');
  }, [removeMessage]);
};
```

Comment: Really awesome solution! Saved me big time