# How to use context in the root layout of Next 13 app folder?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

I want to use my global theme to style the body in the RootLayout of the Next 13 new app folder. How can I use a context in that root layout?

```
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

import ThemeProvider from "./hooks/theme"
import CardsProvider from "./hooks/getCards"

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ThemeProvider>
            <CardsProvider>
              {children}
            </CardsProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: You should make it a client component and make it behave like a provider instead of importing a provider.

Comment: @YoussoufOumar that makes sense. I'll try that and see if it works? Do you think making that change affect the functionality of the layout component other than making it less performant because of the re-render each time?

Comment: Even if it re-renders, its `children` won't, so there would be no big effect here.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a client component `ParentWrapper` for wrapping all the context providers.

For example -

app/ParentWrapper.tsx

```
"use client";
import React from "react";

import ThemeProvider from "./hooks/theme"
import CardsProvider from "./hooks/getCards"

export default function ParentProvider({
    children
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider>
            <CardsProvider>
                {children}
            </CardsProvider>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

And, then using this component in `RootLayout`.

app/RootLayout.tsx

```
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import ParentProvider from './ParentProvider';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ParentProvider>
          {children}
        </ParentProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to style the body with dark/light theme. In example you gave I don't think I can access the Theme from the body.

Comment: Did you find a workaround to this, @Kolom

Comment: @Jay yes I end up putting all my contex providers in the main "layout.tsx". This layout file has 2 children: navbar and {children}. and children in that case is the "page.tsx"

Answer (score 1):

Because the provider is rendered in the RootLayout, the RootLayout itself does not have access to any of the provider’s contents. However, since a provider essentially functions like a regular component, it is possible to pass along any variables or functions from the RootLayout to the provider.

I encountered a similar problem when trying to apply a ‘disable scrolling’ class to the `body` tag whenever a mobile menu is opened. The open/closed state of the menu is stored in variable `isOpen` within my `MobileMenuProvider`, and any change in this state needed to be passed along to the RootLayout. For this, I ended up with the following:

My RootLayout:

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  const [disableScroll, setDisableScroll] = useState<boolean>(false);

  // Wrapped in useCallback(), so it can be used as dependency
  // in useEffect() inside MobileMenuProvider.
  // See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70665603/9413490
  const bodyScrollCallback = useCallback((isOpen: boolean) => {
    setDisableScroll(isOpen);
  }, []);

  return (
    <MobileMenuProvider bodyScrollCallback={bodyScrollCallback}>
      <html lang="nl">
        <body className={disableScroll ? styles.disableScroll : ''}>
          {children}
        </body>
      </html>
    </MobileMenuProvider>
  );
}
```

My `MobileMenuProvider`:

```
function MobileMenuProvider({ children, bodyScrollCallback }: Props) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  // Whenever isOpen changes, call bodyScrollCallback() in RootLayout.
  useEffect(() => {
    bodyScrollCallback(isOpen);
  }, [isOpen, bodyScrollCallback]);

  return (
    <LocalStateProvider value={{
      isOpen,
      setIsOpen,
    }}
    >
      {children}
    </LocalStateProvider>
  );
}
```

This way, the `disableScroll` value in my RootLayout is always identical to the `isOpen` value in `MobileMenuProvider`. Hope this helps!